# How do I use the Dom File API from privileged code?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, gecko

I'm working on a restartless firefox addon. Using firefox developer edition v36. The [MDN page on the Dom File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code) claims that you can import `File` as:

```
const {File, Services} = Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm', {});
```

But [Services.jsm](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/toolkit/modules/Services.jsm) clearly does not export a File Object. I also tried:

```
new contentWindow.File( filename )
```

But this gives a very descriptive NS_ERROR_FAILURE.

Any clues are welcome, thanks

Comment: I put that on MDN, I got that from a StackOverflow topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780396/use-blob-on-firefox-add-on I just tested it though and you're right its not working anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cu.importGlobalProperties(["File"]);
```

[MDN :: Components.utils.importGlobalProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.importGlobalProperties)

Comment: Whoa very cool this works for me! Is this just like `Cu.import` in that it is just a pointer? Does this have to wait for any windows to load?

Comment: It does not need to wait for windows to load. The only downside to this method is that it does not work for arbitrary DOM globals; there's a very specific list of properties for which it works at http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/xpconnect/src/Sandbox.cpp#780 (GlobalProperties::Parse).

Comment: Thanks alot, MDN can be a labyrinth sometimes

Comment: actually, this doesn't work for me. When trying to instantiate a File object I get an exception with properties like: `message: "", result: 2147500037, name: "NS_ERROR_FAILURE"`. The same error I get when using contentWindow.File.

Comment: As a matter of fact I now also have the same problem with the hiddenDOMwINDOW approach, even though that worked before...

Answer (score 0):

[Noitidart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828637/noitidart)  found a workaround:

```
const { Services } = Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm', {})

// And you're holding on to the constructor straight away
//
var domfile = Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.File( filename )
```

I have found another workaround at the same time:

```
// Where window is a contentWindow.
//
var domWindowUtils = window.QueryInterface( Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                     .getInterface( Ci.nsIDOMWindowUtils)

var FileUtils = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm").FileUtils

var nsifile = new FileUtils.File( fileName )
var domfile = domWindowUtils.wrapDOMFile( nsifile )
```

Both approaches are kind of workarounds because they mean you need a loaded window. Currently we found no way to get an interface to it without a window.

Comment: We hope to see a solution rather than workarounds though. These both depend on waiting for `window`s to load. So anyone that sees this please supply a solution if you can :)