# Use Blob on newer firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780396/use-blob-on-firefox-add-on) is outdated:

```
let { Cc, Ci, Cu, CC } = require('chrome');
const {Blob, File} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", {});
console.log(typeof Blob);//undefined
```

How do I import a blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cu.importGlobalProperties(["Blob"]);
```

This works from FF35 onwards. The older approach should work on FF34 and lower.

Related reading at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.importGlobalProperties